# Save dataframe in loop according to unide values in column and password protect it

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, openpyxl, export-to-excel

I am testing the following code but, although generating the files I need (1 file per unique Business Region - which is the index column of the dataframe), it does not password protect it. Any idea?

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from openpyxl.workbook.protection import WorkbookProtection

grouped = list(consolidated_df.groupby(['Business Region']))

passwords = {'AE': 'AE_',
             'CH': 'CH',
             'CZ': 'CZ',
             'DK': 'DK',
             'ES': 'ES',
             'FI': 'FI',
             'FR': 'FR',
             'HQ': 'HQ',
             'NL': 'NL',
             'NO': 'NO',
             'PE': 'PE',
             'PT': 'PT',
             'SE': 'SE',
             'SK': 'SK',
             'TMC': 'TMC',
             'London': 'GB',
             'York': 'GB'}

for df in grouped:
    region = df[0]
    name = str(df[1].index.unique().format()).replace("'", '').replace("[", '').replace("]", '')
    path = os.path.join(filepathtovalidate, f'{name} DM4 Oracle Load.xlsx')
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path)
    df[1].to_excel(writer, index=False)
    workbook = writer.book
    workbook.security = WorkbookProtection(workbookPassword=passwords.get(region))
    writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

To create password-protected Excel files from modifications, you can do this:

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

df1 = pd.DataFrame([['AE', 'BBB']])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['CH', 'XYZ']])

grouped = [df1, df2]

passwords = {'AE': 'AE_',
             'CH': 'CH_'}

for df in grouped:
    region = df[0][0]
    password = passwords.get(region)
    print(password)
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
    ws = wb.active
    # We read the dataframe onto a workbook sheet.
    for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=True, header=True):
        ws.append(r)
    # We protect the book and sheet from changes.
    wb.security.workbookPassword = password
    wb.security.lockStructure = True

    ws.protection.sheet = True
    ws.protection.password = password

    wb.save(f'{region}.xlsx')
```